# How to Create List<T> in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is binded using the following code,

**C#**

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
```

{
    public class data
    {
        public data(int rollno, bool present)
        {
            RollNo = rollno;
            Present = present;
        }
        public int RollNo { set; get; }
        public bool Present { set; get; }
    }

```
public class Data:List<data>
{
   public Data()
    {
       bool Present;
       int RollNo;
        int itemsCount = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            Present= i % 2 == 0;
            RollNo = i;
            Add(new data(RollNo,Present));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**XAML**

```
<my:DataGrid x:Name="dgAttendance" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemSource="{StaticResource Data}">
    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextBoxColumn Header="Role No" Width="50" 
                                  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RollNo}" />
        <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Present" 
                                   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Present}" />
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

What I am supposed to add in `<navigation:Page.Resources>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I followed something like this.

**.CS :**

```
List<data> DataList = new List<data>();
int itemsCount = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
{
     data NewData = new data();
     NewData.Present= i % 2 == 0;
     NewData.RollNo = i;
     DataList.Add(NewData);
}
TxtCompanyName.DataContext = e.Result;
```

**XAML :**

```
<my:DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="277" Margin="20,193,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="799" ItemSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

Comment: u have just created a grid and not binded with data

Answer (score 3):

Is `Data` your custom class? If yes, You need to include the namespace of `Data` class in this file.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't catch it, Data is a custom class

Comment: add `using <Namespace_of_Data_class;` at the beginning of Home.cs. Let me know if you have any issues :)

Comment: I have namespace but how to add in xaml? Is it like `<local:Data x:Key="Data"/>`

Comment: I am asking about `<navigation:Page.Resources>        
        <local:Data x:Key="Data" />
    </navigation:Page.Resources>`